# Changing SenderName in a .msg file

Tags: outlook, outlook-redemption

How can I change the property SenderName and SenderEmailAddress in a .msg file, not from within Outlook?

I know that this is not possible with the Outlook COM, because it is a read only property.

I tried using the class Redemption.RDOSession and the method GetMessageFromMsgFile but all the properties were null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it is very easy:

```
string rdoAddressID = rdoSession.CreateOneOffEntryID("Joe the User", "SMTP", "address@email.com", Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
Redemption.RDOAddressEntry entry = rdoSession.GetAddressEntryFromID(rdoAddressID, Type.Missing);
mail.Sender = entry;
```

Comment: this also adds the "send on behalf of" after the email address. Do you know how can I remove this ? Tnks

Comment: Never mind. I got it. Need to had the same entry to the SendOnBehalfOf property. Thanks